# Create glow effect on save

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to make the borders of my form glow when a function is executed. 
Something like a pulse that's gonna happen when the uptdate function, which is called every 5 seconds, is called. Just as a way to show that the content was saved. How can I do that? I looked in so many places and over many CSS properties but I couldn't come up with something that would create that effect. I am using AngularJS and Bootstrap.

the html

```
<div class=" container col-lg-8" id="right" >
    <div id="delete-button" class="row">
        <a  ng-really-message="Are you sure you want to delete this note?" ng-really-click="deleteNote(note)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash " style="float:left;">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <form >
        <div class="row">
            <input id="note-title" type="text"   class="form-control"  ng-model="title" placeholder="Untitled">
            <div>
                <textarea id="note-body" class="form-control fadein" rows="2" cols="25"
                      ng-model="body" placeholder="Write your note here..." ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div data-fb-like=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want a css glow effect or the code to change element class?

Comment: use `box-shadow` to get glow effect on your container

Comment: a css transition should be enough for glowing borders

Comment: I want it to change the css class. Animate.css with some js has done the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS library, hope it will works for you :

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/